# How can I link *.c files in Visual Studio 2005 using make file option?

Tags: c, visual-studio, makefile, linker

What is the option for linking the source files in Visual Studio in makefile?

I have given it as 'link', but that doesn't work.

The option for compilation is 'cl'.  This is working well.

I want to know the link option.

Answer (score 1):

link is the Visual Studio command. If you open a Visual Studio prompt, it should work.

Check that the link command is in your path.